# IBM Cognos custom application

Tags: jakarta-ee, cognos

We have IBM Cognos software installed with it's own custom tomcat server. Is there any way I can deploy my java EE aplication to this server and use it throught web browser? There is standard tomcat /webapps folder and that unpacks my .war file into specific folder as standard tomcat does, but I'm just not able to get to my application in web browser. There's some kind of filtering that always redirects me to "IBM Cognos Connection" or invalid page.

Thank you for any solution or help

Answer (score 1):

What link are you trying? Usually placing a war file and restarting Cognos BI service is enough to see your app at

```
http://Cognos_ServerName:9300/app_name
```

Although I'd generally not recommend placing custom apps in cognos tomcat, it can cause all sorts of maintenance issues.

Comment: I'm using the same link as you mentioned, but without restarting the service. Now I remember I read somewhere that it should be restarted, but "hot deploy" works just fine on my tomcat, so I silly expected to work on cognos too. Thank you.

Comment: No worries -) Cognos tomcat is usually quite old/stable, so you don't get a lot of features you're used to.